# Logic App return JSON fields if its not null

Tags: json, http, null, response, azure-logic-apps

How do i strip out fields of a JSON object returned in a Logic App HTTP response if the value is null?

Current response message sample:

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Age": 20,
  "Address": null
}
```

But requires:

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Age": 20,
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with an Integration Account and a Liquid Map as this:

```
{   
    {% if content.Address == empty %}
        "Name": "{{ content.Name }}",
        "Age": "{{ content.Age }}"
    {% else %}
        "Name": "{{ content.Name }}",
        "Age": "{{ content.Age }}",
        "Address": "{{ content.Address }}"
    {% endif %}
}
```

Using a **Transform JSON to JSON** shape:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use the logic below in case you expect other fields to be empty besides the Address

```
{   
    {% if content.Name != nil %}
        "Name": "{{ content.Name }}",
    {% endif %}
    {% if content.Age != nil %}
        "Age": "{{ content.Age }}",
    {% endif %}
    {% if content.Address != nil% }
        "Address": "{{ content.Address }}"
    {% endif %}  
}
```